# pythonでK-meansクラスタリングしたいがエラーが出る: ValueError: Can only index by location with a [integer, ...]

Tags: python

#### 解決したいこと

シミュレーションデータの元データからある条件以上を抽出し←「こちらは完了している」

そのデータをクラスタリングして訪問先の抽出を行おうとしているのですがここでエラーが起きてしまいました

#### 実行環境

・Excelに元データがある
・コマンドプロンプトでpythonを開く
・メモ帳にプログラミングを書きhoge.pyで保存
・コマンドプロンプトで実行

#### 発生している問題・エラー

```
C:\datasyori>python hoge.py
    latitude   longitude
0  35.693590  139.712202
1  35.693497  139.712096
2  35.693217  139.712261
3  35.693549  139.712430
4  35.693621  139.712501
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mable\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 769, in _validate_tuple_indexer
    self._validate_key(k, i)
  File "C:\Users\mable\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1378, in _validate_key
    raise ValueError(f"Can only index by location with a [{self._valid_types}]")
ValueError: Can only index by location with a [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array]

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\datasyori\hoge.py", line 95, in <module>
    Cn = C.iloc[Tn,0]
  File "C:\Users\mable\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 961, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "C:\Users\mable\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1458, in _getitem_tuple
    tup = self._validate_tuple_indexer(tup)
  File "C:\Users\mable\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 771, in _validate_tuple_indexer
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types
```

#### 該当するソースコード

```py
#訪問先の抽出

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets, preprocessing
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader

pd.set_option('display.max_rows',600)
#前処理後のcsvを読み込み
yomi=pd.read_csv("simulationkai.csv")
df=pd.read_csv("simulationkai.csv",usecols=["longitude","latitude"])

# DataFrameに変換
print(df.head())
# データの整形
X = df

 
# クラスタリング
cls = KMeans(n_clusters=4)

result = cls.fit(X)
X['cluster'] = result.labels_
PC= pd.DataFrame(X['cluster'])
PC
df.head()
#yomiのデータフレームにcluster(クラスタ番号)を追加する
yomi['cluster_id']=PC
yomi

#yomi(元データにクラスタ番号を追加したもの)をallclsdata.csvに保存する
yomi.to_csv("allclsdata.csv")

D = X.sort_values(by="cluster")
D = D.drop_duplicates(subset='cluster')
D
# 各クラスタ内のデータ数をカウント
V = X['cluster'].value_counts()
V
# 各クラスタの番号とデータ数をclsvalue.csvに保存
V.to_csv("clsvalue.csv")


# クラスタの重心確認
C = pd.DataFrame(result.cluster_centers_)
C

C.iloc[0, :]


lat= X['latitude'].tolist()
lon= X['longitude'].tolist()

clat=C[0].tolist()
clon=C[1].tolist()


#から1800までのクラスタのデータからそれぞれ同じ被験者の重複を省いてデータ人数を取得して順番にCSVにまとめる
from csv import writer
#pp = pd.DataFrame
#ppi =  pd.DataFrame
#yomiからWhile文でN番目のクラスタのデータのみ抽出
i = 0
while i <= 3:
  yomic = yomi[yomi['cluster_id']== i]
#N番目のクラスタdfから被験者idの重複を消す
  yomics = yomic.drop_duplicates(subset=["id_questionnaire"])
#N番目の加工後データの行数をCSVに付け足す
  #file = [i,len(yomics)]
  #ppi = pp.append([file], ignore_index=True)
  #ppi.to_csv("pp.csv")
  list_data=[i,len(yomics)]
  with open('pp.csv', 'a', newline='') as f_object:  
   writer_object = writer(f_object)
   writer_object.writerow(list_data)  
   f_object.close()
  i = i + 1
#else:
  #ppi.to_csv("pp.csv") 

#pp.csv内の人数を降順にしたものをpps.csvに保存
PP = pd.read_csv("pp.csv",names=["cls","people"])
T = PP.sort_values(by=["people"],ascending=False)
T.to_csv("pps.csv")
PP.to_csv("pp.csv")

#pps.csvの上から順番にクラスタ番号を引き出してその番号の座標をCから引き出す
num = 0
while num <= 3:
  Tn = T.iloc[num,0]
  #Tno = Tn + 1
  Cn = C.iloc[Tn,0]
  Cn2 = C.iloc[Tn,1]
  list_data2=[Tn,Cn,Cn2]
  with open('point.csv', 'a', newline='') as f_object:  
   writer_object = writer(f_object)
   writer_object.writerow(list_data2)  
   f_object.close()
  num = num + 1  

dfh = pd.read_csv("point.csv",names=["cluster_id","latitude","longitude"])
B = pd.read_csv("pps.csv",usecols=["people"])
#dfh2= pd.DataFrame(B['people'])
dfh['people']= B
dfh.to_csv("point.csv")
```

#### 自分で試したこと

Cnの値に対しての型がエラーが起きているようなのですが勉強不足でよく理解できていないです

#### 補足情報

Python 3.10.4 (tags/v3.10.4:9d38120, Mar 23 2022, 23:13:41) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: 「Tn」の値は何になっていますか？

Comment: すみません調べて使えそうなコードをコピペしてきたので詳しくはわからないのですがTnなどには決まった数定数などは入れておりません

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/n48ioou96ixjva) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: 解答していただいたのですが解決していなかったため他のサイトでも質問させていただきました。申し訳ありません

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず，エラー情報ですが 95行目の

```
Cn = C.iloc[Tn,0]
```

で発生し，内容は「位置情報ベースのインデキシング（ .iloc[] ）は『整数，整数スライス，整数リスト，ブール型配列』のみ受け（入れ）ることができる」です。
そこで， 95行目の直前に

```
print(num, Tn, type(Tn))
```

を挿入して，適当に入力データ（simulationkai.csv）を作って実行してみたところ，以下のことがわかりました。
・1回目の実行ではエラーは発生せず， Tnは整数値（1, 0, 2, 3）
・2回目以降の実行ではエラーが発生し， Tnは str型（文字列）の 'cls'
このことから，恐らく1回目に実行した際に作られた csvファイルが影響していると考え， Tn -> T -> PP -> pp.csv と遡って 76行目の

```
with open('pp.csv', 'a', newline='') as f_object:
```

に辿り着きました。そして，この行が whileループの初回（i = 0）でも実行されているために，過去に作られた pp.csv に追記（'a'）しているようです。そこで，下記のように whileループの初回のみ上書き（'w'）になるように変更したところエラーは発生しなくなりました。

```
with open('pp.csv', 'w' if i == 0 else 'a', newline='') as f_object:
```

Comment: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation levelと加えたところにエラーが出てしまったのですがこれは空白を合わせないといけないという意味でしょうか

Comment: 他は何もせずに，'a' を 'w' if i == 0 else 'a' に入れ替えてみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: あ、それも入れ替えてます

Comment: 少し言葉足らずだったようです。元々の状態から 'a' を 'w' if i == 0 else 'a' に書き換えればインデントがずれることなく修正できるという意味です。